# Image only dispay in one instance of Vaadin

Tags: java, image, singleton, vaadin

Im new to java and Vaadin. I`ve made a simple project with maven. Its working, but some behaviours are not like it ment to be. Mostly important png image shows only in one window. App is suppose to show images in many windows instead.

There is an Admin class that contains next and previous button, these are working but after opening up client window png from admin window dissapears.

Is this a common issue? Do I have to spec somehow that Image object can be used multiple times?

ClientWindow.class

AdminWindow.class - singleton, contains list of client Windows reminds them of current image change

Displayer.class - singleton,

Ive tried even copying Image before replacing in layout. Do anyone have idea whats going on?

This is displayer class:

> package multiUser;

```
//import java.io.File;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.vaadin.server.FileResource;
import com.vaadin.server.ThemeResource;
import com.vaadin.server.VaadinService;
import com.vaadin.ui.Image;

public class Displayer {

//deklaracja singletonu
private final static Displayer instance = new Displayer();

public static Displayer getInstance() {
    return instance;
}

private List<Image> images = new ArrayList();



String basepath = VaadinService.getCurrent()
                  .getBaseDirectory().getAbsolutePath();




Image currentImage;
int currentImageIndex=0;

private Displayer() {
    fillListImages();
    setFirstImageAsCurrent();
}



private void setFirstImageAsCurrent() {
    currentImage = images.get(currentImageIndex);
}

private void fillListImages() {
    for (int i = 1 ; i<4  ; i++){
        FileResource resource = new FileResource(new File(basepath +
            "/WEB-INF/images/" + i +".png"));
        images.add(new Image("",resource));

    }   
}

public void nextImage() {
    if(currentImageIsLast()) {
        currentImage = images.get(0);

    } else{ 
        currentImageIndex = images.indexOf(currentImage);
        currentImageIndex = currentImageIndex + 1;
        currentImage = images.get(currentImageIndex);

    }
}
public void previousImage() {
    if(currentImageIsFirst()) {
        currentImage = images.get(images.size() - 1);

    } else{ 
        currentImageIndex = images.indexOf(currentImage);
        currentImageIndex = currentImageIndex - 1;
        currentImage = images.get(currentImageIndex);

    }
}


private boolean currentImageIsFirst() {
    return currentImage == images.get(0);
}



private boolean currentImageIsLast() {
    return currentImage == images.get(images.size()-1);
}



public Image getCurrentImage() {
    return currentImage;
}
```

}

Ok, I solved this issue. i deleted imges list and make geyCurrentImage() method to resolve resource for image every time its called :

Working code:

*
    package multiUser;

```
//import java.io.File;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.vaadin.server.FileResource;
import com.vaadin.server.ThemeResource;
import com.vaadin.server.VaadinService;
import com.vaadin.ui.Image;

public class Displayer {

//deklaracja singletonu
private final static Displayer instance = new Displayer();

public static Displayer getInstance() {
    return instance;
}





String basepath = VaadinService.getCurrent()
                  .getBaseDirectory().getAbsolutePath();





int currentImageIndex=1;
int imagesAmount= 3;

private Displayer() {


}




private Image getImageResource(int index) {
    FileResource resource = new FileResource(new File(basepath + "/WEB-INF/images/" + index +".png"));
    Image image =  new Image("",resource);
    return image; 
}



public void nextImage() {
    if(currentImageIndex==imagesAmount) {
        currentImageIndex=1 ;       
    } 
    else{           
        currentImageIndex = currentImageIndex + 1;                  
    }
}
public void previousImage() {
    if(currentImageIndex==1) {
        currentImageIndex = imagesAmount;

    } else{             
        currentImageIndex = currentImageIndex - 1;          
    }
}




public Image getCurrentImage() {
    Image currentImage = getImageResource(currentImageIndex);
    return currentImage;
}
```

}
*

Comment: Please share your code so we can see exactly what you are doing

Answer (score 0):

You can not add the same image object to different component. A component (image) can have only one parent. But different images may have the same resource.

Instead of `List<Image>` use `List<Resource>` and when you add the Image to the parent Component always use new Image object with `getCurrentResource()`.

Comment: So when I copy image object its still same? Do I have to manipulate resource path in this class instead of image list index?

Comment: BTW, how do you copy image object?

Comment: I was making another Image ibject and image1 = image2. Problem is already solved.